# Can I receive a Date attribute from rest response, as a LocalDateTime or LocalDate in my application?

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, jackson

I have this class:

```
public class MyLocalApplicationClass {
    private String name
    private LocalDateTime creationDate;
    private String createdBy;
}
```

And in a response that I receive from a rest service I get this object (as a json):

```
public class MyRemoteApplicationClass {
    private String name
    private Date creationDate;
    private String createdBy;
}
```

So when I send the request I get the value (json) of creationDate from MyRemoteApplicationClass like this:

```
{
    “name”:”anything”,
    "creation_date": 1666190973000,
    "created_by": “anyone”
}
```

So I was wondering if it is possible to receive this as a LocalDateTime or I should receive it as a Date and then cast it to LocalDateTime (think this is my best option)?

Because I am trying to receive it as a LocalDateTime but it throws this error:

```
raw timestamp (1656015404000) not allowed for 
java.time.LocalDateTime: need additional information such as an
offset or time-zone (see class Javadocs)
```

Also, I tried to receive it as `LocalDate` only, but it throws this error (which I already added the dependency of jsr310 and also added the serializer and deserializer with this annotations `@JsonSerialize(using = LocalDateSerializer.class) @JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateDeserializer.class)` so I think the real problem is the warning) and warning:

```
Java 8 date/time type `java.time.DateTimeException` not supported
by default: add Module "com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310"
to enable handling (through reference chain:
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException["cause"])

WARN -- com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException:
Invalid value for EpochDay (valid values -365243219162 - 365241780471): 1656015404000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## TL;DR

There are several possible solutions:

- Receive the timestamp as is, and perform parsing in the constructor;
- Apply global configurations by registering the `JavaTimeModule` and applying the required timestamp precision.
- Implement a custom Deserializer.

Let's walk through these options.

## Parse the Timestamp inside the Constructor

We can declare *all-args constructor* inside the `MyLocalApplicationClass` and annotate each argument with `@JsonProperty`. The *contranctior parameter* `creationDate` should be received as `long`, since it would be parsed from epoch millisecond to `LocalDateTime` manually.

Here's it might look like:

```
public class MyLocalApplicationClass {
    private String name;
    private LocalDateTime creationDate;
    private String createdBy;
    
    public MyLocalApplicationClass(@JsonProperty("name") String name,
                                   @JsonProperty("creation_date") long creationDate,
                                   @JsonProperty("created_by") String createdBy) {
        this.name = name;
        this.createdBy = createdBy;
        this.creationDate = Instant
            .ofEpochMilli(creationDate)
            .atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC)
            .toLocalDateTime();
    }
}
```

## Apply global Configurations

Another option would be apply global deserialization configurations.

But that would require changing the type of `creationDate` property to `Instant`.

To configure `ObjectMapper` properly we would need to take two steps:

- register `JavaTimeModule` module;
- instruct `ObjectMapper` about the precision of the timestamp by setting deserialization property `DeserializationFeature.READ_DATE_TIMESTAMPS_AS_NANOSECONDS` to `false`.

For that, we can place `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder` and `ObjectMapper` as Beans into the Spring's Context.

```
@Configuration
public class JsonConfig {
    
    @Bean
    public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder() {
        return new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder();
    }

    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        return jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder()
            .build()
            .registerModule(new JavaTimeModule())
            .configure(DeserializationFeature.READ_DATE_TIMESTAMPS_AS_NANOSECONDS, false);
    }
}
```

**Note** that `creationDate` should be of type `Instant`, data-binding annotations in this case are needed only because property and field names doesn't match (*they are unrelated to conversion*)

```
public class MyLocalApplicationClass {
    private String name;
    @JsonProperty("creation_date")
    private Instant creationDate;
    @JsonProperty("created_by")
    private String createdBy;
    
    // getter, setters, etc.
}
```

## Simplified global Configuration

As [*@M. Deinum*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2696260/m-deinum) has pointed out in the comments, required precision can be configured through the `application.properties`:

```
spring.jackson.deserialization.READ_DATE_TIMESTAMPS_AS_NANOSECONDS=false
```

And we can **remove both Beans** (*mapper and mapper builder*) declared in the configuration class in the example above because [`JacksonAutoConfiguration`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jackson/JacksonAutoConfiguration.html) would grab and register all known modules at the application start up.

Declaration of `MyLocalApplicationClass` would be identical to the one shown above (`creationDate` is of type `java.time.Instant`).

## Create a custom Deserializer

Lastly, we can implement a custom deserializer by extending [`StdDeserializer`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.9.1/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/deser/std/StdDeserializer.html) and overriding its `abstract` method `deserialize()`.

```
public class DateTimeDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<LocalDateTime> {
    
    public DateTimeDeserializer() {
        super(LocalDateTime.class);
    }
    
    @Override
    public LocalDateTime deserialize(JsonParser p,
                                     DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JacksonException {
    
    
        JsonNode node = p.getCodec().readTree(p);
        long timestamp = node.longValue();
        
        return Instant
            .ofEpochMilli(timestamp)
            .atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC)
            .toLocalDateTime();
    }
}
```

To instruct Jackson to apply this deserializer it can specified by the means of `using` property of `@JsonDeserialize` annotation, which should be placed on top of `creationDate` field.

```
public class MyLocalApplicationClass {

    private String name;

    @JsonDeserialize(using = DateTimeDeserializer.class)
    @JsonProperty("creation_date")
    private LocalDateTime creationDate;

    @JsonProperty("created_by")
    private String createdBy;
    
    // getter, setters, etc.
}
```

Comment: The `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder` automiatcally detects the `JavaTimeModule` you don't need to add it. You can also set the `spring.jackson.deserialization.READ_DATE_TIMESTAMPS_AS_NANOSECONDS=false` and then can omit the configuration completely.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks, that's a valuable suggestion. I know that modules can be declared as registered automatically, but I wasn't aware that timestamp precision can be customized through the application properties. I've improved the answer and incorporated this information.

Comment: Spring will detect well known modules automatically, you don't need to do anything for this. You don't even need the bean, ditch the configuration completely.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thank's, thanks an aha moment... So I've misread the documentation [*"auto-registration for all Module beans"*](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jackson/JacksonAutoConfiguration.html) (the third bullet-point), only custom modules should be declared as beans, and all the standard modules shipped by Jackson would be discovered automatically, right?

Comment: Not just standard modules shipped by Jackson some other well known ones are registered as well (like the hibernate one for instance).